# username depednt redirection from login page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create  login page where each user  redirect to page should be based on username. For example If Manager login, then it should redirect to manager landing page after login and when it login to staff page then it should redirect to staff . Here is my code of  login page . But my code is generating error and not working . mysql table have user name "user" with four column which are (id, username, password and user_redirect_uri) Here is the code

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
      header('Location: $url');
    exit;
}
 
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
     $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, user_redirect_uri FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,  $id, $username, $hashed_password, $url);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                          
                        } else{
                            // Password is not valid, display a generic error message
                            $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Username doesn't exist, display a generic error message
                    $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<header><center> <img src = "logo.png" height = "100" width = "180"></center></header>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card mt-5">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">
                        <h4>Login</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">

        <?php 
        if(!empty($login_err)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
        }        
        ?>


        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
<div class="col-md-4">
                <label></label>
             
            </div>    
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
                <label></label>
               <label></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <center> <input type="submit"  style="background-color: #3fbbc0;" value="Login">
            </div>
         
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error is it generating?

Comment: You're doing `header('Location: $url')` before you do the database query that sets `$url`. That should be at the end, not the beginning. Also, variables are only substituted inside double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: @Barmar still the same error when i placed it after database querry. Can you reset in code if possible sir

Comment: Never store plain text passwords php has failed nktions to hash and verify it

Comment: ok but whats the issue in my code?

Comment: It needs to be `header("Location: $url");`. What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Ps. I don't see how this will ever log anyone in correctly. You're checking the password in the sql, which implies the password is stored in plain text. But then later you're also using password_verify which suggests the password is stored hashed. Only one of these techniques can work at one time. If you use both, login will always fail because one of the methods will not find a match. The recommendation is always to use hashed passwords.

Comment: Also, for this part: `f(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
      header('Location: $url')`...if you want to redirect an _existing, logged-in user_ (which you never mentioned as being a requirement, in your last question about this!), then you'll need to store the redirect URL in the Session when you log the user in, so you can re-use it here without needing another database query.  Or, instead of redirecting here, just show a "you are already logged in" message instead of the form, and let the user navigate themselves to wherever they actually want to go.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use a session variable to store "user_redirect_uri" then on the top after checking if logged in get the url.
2. On the top after session_start() use ob_start()

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: can you edit my code if possible sir bec i am not getting where is the exact issue

Comment: After session_start() next line ob_start()  and after validating user use $_SESSION["url"]=$url; then on the top after checking if user logged in assign $url = $_SESSION["url"];

Comment: still issue// Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;  
                           $_SESSION["url"]=$url;

Comment: Have you use ob_start()? Please post the  error

Comment: yes i did, when i tyr to login then following error occur : Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.    can you alter my above code , wil be thankful